# PHP connecting to database

Tags: php, database, easyphp

I have created a web chat application and whenever I enter the username and password I created it comes up with this error:

> Warning: include(../errors/err.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Win8\Documents\EasyPHP\data\localweb\web chat\chatbox\inc\connection.php on line 10

> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../errors/err.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Win8\Documents\EasyPHP\data\localweb\web chat\chatbox\inc\connection.php on line 10

What does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

It is a warning that there is a missed file which cannot be opened, and it's name is err.php. Maybe you have to create an empty err.php file in C:\Users\Win8\Documents\EasyPHP\data\localweb\web chat\chatbox\errors.

Comment: It is that the only possible reason why it is coming up with that error?

Comment: this is my error.php file:      <?php
 if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
 $error = $_GET['error'];
?>
<html lang="EN">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   .holder {
    padding:3px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:10%;
    display:table;
    border:solid 1px #cccccc;
    border-width: thin;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div class="holder">
  <label for="errormsg">Note: </label><label for="error"><?php echo $error; ?></label>
 </div> 
 </body>
</html>
<?php } ?>

Comment: What is the document root of your webserver?

Comment: If you are not familiar with php, can you tell me how did you configured the web server so I can determine the case?

Comment: i remove the err.php and now there is no error, however there is just a blank page?

Comment: the document root is localhost8080

Comment: another person configured the webserver so i dont know

Comment: You removed the err.php from where? and what the application link?

Comment: i removed the err.php from the connect.php file and yes, it is just blank now

Comment: What is your application link, for example: http://localhost:8080/somelink

Comment: localhost:8080/web%20chat/

Comment: the username joe     password joe123

Comment: Please check the database connection settings

Comment: where should i check ?

Comment: I'm using easyphp

Comment: look for configuration file like: config.php file in 'web chat' folder and subfolders

Comment: the only other file similiar to that is dbchat.sql

Comment: Ok, to help you more. Where have you got the 'web chat' script from?

Comment: a friend created it and zipped it over

Comment: Ok, how many files (not folders) in 'web chat'? can you tell me what are the files included?

Comment: connection.php error.php home.php login.php send_save_chat.php view.php index.php reg.php submit.php

Comment: Ok, when you open connection.php do you find some keywords like:
username, password, database,.. etc.

Comment: indeed there is

Comment: Ok, do you have mysql server or any dbms?

Comment: local8080:phpmyadmin

Comment: Ok, you have to check the settings in the connection.php file like the followings:
$database = 'your used database';
$database_user = 'root';
$database_server = 'localhost';

Sorry, I have to leave now but I will check your response once I get back

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that on line 10 of `connection.php` you are trying to do an `<?php include 'err.php'; ?>`, but your program cannot find it.

I would check the file structure of `err.php` and make the appropriate correction.